# How do I get nativescript_google_maps_sdk to work?

Tags: nativescript

I have a new installation of Nativescript, when I run my app after installing nativescript_google_maps_sdk, I get the following error;

- Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.*

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~16.2.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.6.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.6.2",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.6.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.18",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~16.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.6"
  }
}
```

I've tried different Node and NS versions